# mongodb $pull not working php

Tags: php, mongodb, pull, unset

I have this object in my db.

```
    Array(
[_id] => MongoId Object
    (
        [$id] => 4fcdb3b8749d786c03000002
    )

[email] => foo@bar.com
[folder] => Array
    (
        [root] => Array
            (
                [feeds] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [feedID] => MongoId Object
                                    (
                                        [$id] => 4fcdaa9e749d786c03000001
                                    )

                                [title] => title.com
                            )

                    )

                [title] => root
            )

    )


[status] => 1
[username] => foouser)
```

I want pull just item [0] from [feeds].
I use this code but it not working:

```
$usersCollection->update(array("username" => "foouser"), array('$pull'=> array('folder'=>array('root'=>array('feeds'=>array('feedID'=>$id))))));
```

When I use this $unset instead of $pull, full of [folder] will be gone.

Comment: Just a guess, but is your `$id` a string, or a proper MongoID? i.e. `$real_id = new MongoId("$id");` ??

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongoid.construct.php

Comment: It's a MongiID,it's not problem. I can not pull root also with this: $usersCollection->update(array("username" => "foouser"), array('$pull'=> array('folder'=>'root')));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the *full* value of the array element. You also have to use *'folder.root.feeds'* as that's the field you want to pull from. You don't want to pull the array element inside `folder` from being affected.

On the shell, you would run:

```
db.so.update(
    { 'username' : 'foouser' },
    { $pull:
        { 'folder.root.feeds' :
            {
                "feedId" : ObjectId("4fcdaa9e749d786c03000001"),
                "title" : "title.com"
            }
        }
    }
);
```

And in PHP, that would translate to:

```
$c->update(
    array( 'username' => 'foouser' ),
    array( '$pull' =>
        array( 'folder.root.feeds' =>
            array(
                'feedId' => new MongoId('4fcdaa9e749d786c03000001'),
                'title' => 'title.com',
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Works for me: http://derickrethans.nl/files/dump/so-10893490.php.txt You do have a recent version of MongoDB I hope?

Comment: just copy your code and worked.I think problem was my insert.another question,how can I use the $ if I dont know 'root'? folder.$.feeds?